# Download after clicking submit button in mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to download a file after clicking the button in this [link](http://'https://6c323804b035a92669497a491abd6e0829440b96.googledrive.com/host/0Bz32CQV6M3iUeUNwQXVUdlU0dVk/fragment.html').

I am using the following code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(laturl)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.submit()
```

But nothing happens. What do I do ?